# Graphs: the best path

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

Assume we have a path in an undirected cyclic weighted graph. Assuming we have an engine that can find a path from node A to node B in such a graph, is there an easy way/algorithm to figure out if the given path from A to B is at least X% better than any other disjoint path from A to B? By disjoint I mean two paths may not share any edges.

Comment: When you mean cyclic, do you mean it's a cycle?

Comment: I mean it has cycles.

Comment: Perhaps this paper might be of use: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=78636

Comment: @JosephMalkevitch: we already have A* based search engine.